# Design a database using binary representation

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to clarify this as I am surely not an expert in Databases and might have got it wrong.

I have a task to design a small address book database (name, phone number, etc) using a straightforward binary representation in any language.

I was thinking that I need to create a database, say in Python and store data in the binary format so I wrote this.

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('address_book.db')
cur = con.cursor()
users = (
    (1, 'USER1', 'Surname1', 'Address1'),
    (2, 'USER2', 'Surname2', 'Address2'),
)
# Convert all data in users to the binary representation 
new_arr = ()
for i in users:
    tuple_to_append = ()
    for j in i:
        if isinstance(j, int):
            tuple_to_append += (bin(j),)
        elif isinstance(j, str):
            tuple_to_append += (''.join(map(bin, bytearray(j, encoding='utf-8'))),)
    new_arr += (tuple_to_append,)

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users("
            "user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            "first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
            "last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
            "address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)")

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", new_arr)
con.commit()
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY`, not `PRIMARY_KEY`...

Comment: @Shawn thanks for a catch. Python didn't complain though

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "straightforward binary representation in any language".  Indeed, a database format will store its data in some specialized binary (not text) file.  But the real benefit to sqlite database is that its code (or library) has been ported to many, many languages, but that really does not have anything to do with the "binary representation" of the database file.  Instead, the availability in many languages comes from the purposeful work of many people to make the sqlite library available in many languages.

Comment: Is this for a class (i.e. homework)?

Comment: @CPerkins it's actually one of the challenges from pragmatic programmer new edition, I will contact authors to get more clarification on that. thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

> **Am I on the right track?**

Perhaps on an unnecessary track as text is actually stored in UTF-8 (generally) and in UTF-16(if the connection is opened via the sqlite3_open16 routine). Typically UTF-8 is used.

Perhaps consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS পরীক্ষা ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS পরীক্ষা (name TEXT, altname1 BLOB, altname2 REAL, altname3 VARCHAR(20), altname4 CHARVAR(-20));
INSERT INTO পরীক্ষা VALUES('Test','ტესტი','thử nghiệm','    テスト','ටෙස්ට්');
SELECT * FROM পরীক্ষা;
```

Here all the values and the table name are the word Test in different languages. The above works and the result from the select is :-

[image]

---

You might wonder, why didn't saving a non-numeric as REAL not fail, or how can you have a negative number of characters as per CHARVAR(-20).

SQlite in regards to column and data types is not typical. In SQlite column types are only an indication of the type of data. In SQLite you can actually store any type of data in any type of column (as the above demonstrates).

In fact there are only 5 column types (type affinity is SQlite's term) these are :-

1. INTEGER
2. REAL
3. TEXT
4. BLOB
5. NUMERIC

Any other acceptable term e.g. is converted to one of the above,

- according to the comment
- > PRIMARY KEY, not PRIMARY_KEY
- you had INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY coded and said :-
- > Python didn't complain though
- The above  was taken as the type being `INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY`

The conversion rules (applied in the given order)

1. If the type includes **INT** then INTEGER affinity (so INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY has INTEGER affinity, as would PRIMARY_KEY INTEGER)
2. If the type includes **CHAR**, **TEXT** or **CLOB** then TEXT affinity (hence VARCHAR(20) and CHARVAR(-20) have a type affinity of TEXT.
3. If the type includes **BLOB** the BLOB affinity.
4. If the type includes **REAL**, **FLOA** or **DOUB** then REAL affinity.
5. Otherwise NUMERIC affinity.

If the following were used to define a column `テスト テスト` (yes it works) then the affinity would be NUMERIC as the column name is `テスト` and the type is the second part `テスト`, which drops through to 5. Otherwise NUMERIC.

Comment: thanks for the very useful information ! it's clear why it happened to me, didn't know about this peculiar behaviour of sqlite

Comment: it's not very clear why テスト テスト defines a NUMERIC though @MikeT

Comment: @ren it's because it doesn't have INT, CHAR, TEXT, CLOB, BLOB, REAL FLOAT or DOUB as part of the column type (the second occurrence of テスト). I should have posted the link [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)